# rendering of a bound {{stuff}} to a property set in Observable subscription delayed several seconds in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, binding, observable

In my markup I have the following iterator.

```
<div class="...">
  <div *ngFor="let thing of stuff">{{thing}}</div>
</div>
```

On each key being typed, there's a method updating the back field *stuff* being invoked. The part that I can't explain is the surprise that it works but is delayed depending on the source of data being fetched to populate the back field.

```
onTypingThatWorksButDelayed(text: string) {
  this.thing = text;
  this.service.getStuff(this.thing)
    .subscribe(next => {
      this.stuff = next;
      console.log(this.stuff);
    });
}


onTypingThatWorksImmediately(text: string) {
  if (text === "beep")
    this.stuff = ["uno", "duo"];
  else
    this.stuff = ["shabaroo"];
}
```

The service itself is designed along the following lines (and takes a second or so to read the maps API, of course, which I didn't expect to cause any problems because I'm working with *Observable*. I understood that doing so, will make the internal processes of Angular stop and wait until a value is delivered.

```
getStuff(thing: string): Observable<string[]> {
  return new Observable<string[]>(_ => {
    const coder = new google.maps.Geocoder()
      .geocode({ ... }, (
        results: google.maps.GeocoderResult[],
        status: google.maps.GeocoderStatus) => {

          let output = [];
          if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
            output = results.map(...);

          _.next(output);
          _.complete();
        });
    });
}
```

Am I mistaken about the purpose of *Observable*? Can I bind the field iterator so it updates immediately (since the console output has the latest data, I know it's there in the client)?

**edit**

I noticed, to my biggest surprise, that the update of the *{{stuff}}* element **does occur**. The thing is that it takes several seconds before that actually takes place. Please note - the property get the new value immediately (confirmed by consologging where it's clear that the update is present. However, the rendered value in the double curlies takes, maybe, 8 or 12 seconds before it changes!

I can't say what's it about due to ignorance but it's such a weird occurrence that I'm assuming that someone more competent will recognize it and suggest something clever.

Comment: The delay happens because `Geocoder` needs some time to make calls. You can't do much about it, except maybe to use a `trackBy` in `*ngFor`. Seems it might be useful in your case. Other that that I would probably use a Subject instead of returning an Observable from `getStuff()` because you invoke it on every keyboard stroke so you also create many Observables. And you wrote - "since the console output has the latest data" - please create a demo in stackblitz.com. That can't be true, according to your code snipepts

Comment: @fromZerotoHero It might be me not explaining sufficiently well. Sorry. The delay fetching the data is understandable **but** it's not what's puzzling me. I understand that assigning *next* ot the property and then consologouting it should display the same contents in the console as in the bound DIVs but it appears not to. I'm not sure how to reproduce it on the suggested site because Google Maps have this key-thingy that registers with my site and can't be run from another application. What more could I do to investigate and inspect the issue?

Comment: One thing you can do is console.log in every function and every callback  ( `console.log('write where you place it', thing, new Date().getTime())` ). So you should get a better picture when what happens

Comment: @fromZerotoHero Darn... That's what I already did. That's how I arrive in the conclusion that binding to a field that's being set from the *next* in a subscription is setting the property correct **but** fails to update to the *{{stuff}}* (until the next keystroke upon which it becomes updated but then again becomes one step behind). Not sure how to consolog the actual binding, though... The thing I have now is that *console.log(this.stuff)* contains e.g. 3 elements **but** *{{stuff}}* prints e.g. 5. At next stroke, itäs e.g. 2 in the former and 3 in the latter. Weird.

Comment: @fromZerotoHero I just discovered something even more strange - apparently, the issue is not **lack of update** but rather a **very slow update**. I can't say it gives me more wisdom in the issue but I hope that someone else might realize something. (NB. The delay is over 10 seconds! That's why I missed it originally.)